# How to remove the callout from the popup, bubble or cloud?

Tags: popup, customization, openlayers, openstreetmap

I am switching from Google Maps to Open Street Map and starting to work with the API. From the code examples, I could not find one with custom popups. How do I remove the ugly arrow or callout that points the bubble to the marker?

[image: callout]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [OpenLayers.Popup.Anchored](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Popup/Anchored-js.html#OpenLayers.Popup.Anchored) or modify popup style.